# Converting multiple points to multiple polygons - ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, arcgis-10.6, polygonize

How can I convert multiple points to multiple (tiny polygons)?
I need to execute a merge function and I need the points to be polygons so that the toolbox can do its job and join multiple polygon shapes together (the points, their buffer, and other shapefiles).

If I try to convert them to lines first the map will be populated by a jumble of strange lines interconnecting the points!

It is very important that the points are not joined together and that they retain their unique information as they need to be treated as separate "entities" for analysis reasons.

What tool and options should I use to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @chlha! I think you're looking for the [Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-a-buffer-around-a-feature.htm) tool.

Comment: Buffer *may* join nearby features (closer than `2 * d`). Points can be unioned to multipoint, so there is no requirement to convert before unioning.

Comment: Convert to raster, raster to polygon.

Comment: Hi Felix, if I do so, will all the values in the attribute table still be there(Points represents buildings and have different fields that need to be retained, such as name, category, local authority, etc). ?

Comment: I think I will go for Joseph solution. it is actually the easiest way and it retains each point information! Thank you.